# Bijective function without knowing codomain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found in my friend's notes that the function $f(x) = (x-3)^\frac{1}{2}$, where $x$ is any positive real number, has inverse $g(x) = x^2 + 3$. I am confused as here $f(x)$ is not bijective if codomain is $\mathbb{R}$. So how can we find its inverse? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Typically, you just understand (without stating clearly) that the inverse only applies where it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> I found in my friends notes that the function $f(x) = (x-3)^{1/2}$ ,where x is any positive real number

Really *any* positive real number? I suppose only for $x-3\ge 0 \iff x \ge 3$.

Other than that, if the domain is $[3,+\infty)$, then you are right that the codomain needs to be (restricted to) $[0,+\infty)$ for $f$ to be surjective and then also bijective.

Comment: So what we conclude  about inverse of f(x) if given x>3 or x=3

Comment: If the domain consists of all real numbers satisfying $x \ge 3$, then $f$ is a bijection if the codomain is as I wrote. If the codomain isn't specified, it can be _assumed_ or _made_ to be a bijection by (implicitly or explicitly) taking the codomain as required.